# how to sum values then paste it to another row and so on in the same grouping-power query

Tags: powerquery, data-cleaning, m

[image]

I have 2 problems in power query need to be solved as below:

1. I made a custom column `End Inv`., which its calculation is: `End Inv= Begin Inv.+ Delta`
   But the next day begin Inv. should be equal to the End Inv..
   e.g. orange 10/24 End Inv. should be 23382, so the next day 10/25 begin inv should be 23382 also.
2. Different items' Begin Inv. and End Inv should be calculate themselves

I tried:

1. In most case, it seems easy to do in Excel, but it has different items, and actually items would be much more than 2 kinds in this case, so I rather not to calculate in excel.
2. I checked [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGF2-qfzDQs) and find something useful:

It has a approach to refer to previous row, but what I want is refer to previous End Inv ****and then** add it to another cell, then next row and so on**...It is harder then the youtube case.

I just learned to use power query 2 weeks, if there's any good place to learn it please also advise, thanks stack overflow community!!

The result should be like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you have an error in your sample data. Begin inventory for grapes on 10/24 is two different numbers which changes the overall outcome between your two screenshots.

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your question? If so, please toggle checkmark for that answer to mark issue as solved

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching the problem incorrectly by trying to directly modify the beginning inventory column. This is a source column that you wouldn't want to directly change, but rather leverage as a part of creating a new column.. I'd do the following steps

1. Create a new column called `StartBalance` which is going to sum your original `Begin Inv.` plus all delta's LESS THAN record's date field.

```
    Table.AddColumn(Source, "StartBalance", each let zDate = [Date],zItem = [Item] in List.Sum({[BeginInv], List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Date] < zDate and [Item] = zItem)[Delta])}),type number))
```

2. Create an `EndingBalance` column that sums `StartBalance` with `Delta` column

```
    = Table.AddColumn(CreateStartBalanceColumn, "EndBalance", each List.Sum({[StartBalance],[Delta]}),type number)
```

3. Remove the original column Beg Inv.

You might have to change the naming a bit to make sure they match exactly as yours but here's where I started and how it ended...

### Start

[image]

### Completed

[image]

Also, when making these columns, make sure to not use `+` as there are `null` values in columns. Example `100 + null = null`. Instead use `List.Sum({[firstCol],[secondCol]})`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Results table is incorrect due to your seeming to have changed the first starting inventory inappropriately, the following can do what you show. It uses the `List.Generate` function to perform the calculations and transformations:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Begin Inv.", Int64.Type}, {"Delta", Int64.Type}}),
   
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Item"}, {
        {"Calc Table", (t)=> 
        Table.FromRecords(
            List.Generate(
                ()=>[dt=t[Date]{0},bi=t[#"Begin Inv."]{0}, dl=t[Delta]{0},ei=t[#"Begin Inv."]{0} + t[Delta]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(t),
                each [dt=t[Date]{[idx]+1}, bi=[ei], dl=t[Delta]{[idx]+1},ei=[ei] + t[Delta]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                each Record.FromList(
                        {[dt]} & {[bi]} & {[dl]} & {[ei]},{"Date","Begin Inv.","Delta","End Inv."}))
                       )}
                }),
    
    #"Expanded Calc Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Calc Table", {"Date", "Begin Inv.", "Delta", "End Inv."}),
    #"Set Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Calc Table",
        List.Zip({
            List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Calc Table")),
            {type date, Int64.Type,Int64.Type,Int64.Type}
            })
            )
in
    #"Set Types"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Item"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn( #"Added Index", "CumTotal", each List.Sum(List.FirstN( #"Added Index"[Delta],[Index]+1))),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Cum Total", "Ending Inventory", each List.Max(#"Added Index"[#"Begin Inv."])  + [CumTotal])
    in Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Beginning Inventory", each [Ending Inventory]-[Delta]), type table [Date=date] }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Beginning Inventory", "Delta", "Ending Inventory"}, {"Date", "Beginning Inventory", "Delta", "Ending Inventory"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]